# How to substract two tables SUM values in a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables. I got the "SUM" from them. Now I need to subtract and get the value. How do I get this?

Table1

```
SELECT SUM(ItemHeader.InQty) AS NEW_BAL1, ItemID 
FROM ItemHeader  
GROUP BY ItemID
```

Table2

```
SELECT SUM(IssueDetail.Qty) AS NEW_BAL, ItemID 
FROM IssueDetail 
GROUP BY ItemID
```

Both are my tables.

Now I need to get subtract table1 value from table2 value.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you? You didn't state how you were presenting the end results (view, function, stored procedure) or if you need to reuse the summations later on in code. So the simplest is just to wrap each `SELECT` in parentheses and then do the math on those values in another `SELECT`

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(IssueDetail.Qty) AS NEW_BAL, ItemID FROM IssueDetail GROUP BY ItemID)
    - (SELECT SUM(ItemHeader.InQty) AS NEW_BAL1, ItemID FROM ItemHeader GROUP BY ItemID) as [difference]
```